# NetBeans 7.2.1 Running old code

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been working on a project for school and recently ran into an error. I realized that NetBeans is not updating code for GUI items that I have updated for my project. It doesn't update on the GUI designer nor when I view in designer preview or even when I run my program. The code that is always being ran is from 2 days ago. I opened an old project and this is not an issue. So far i have deleted the Cache, Cleaned the project and I have Auto Compile on save on. I reinstalled NetBeans as well. Any Suggestions?

Comment: applet or swing or application??

Comment: Could you clarify some points:

 - How have you cleared the cache?
 - Does the project workspace proper activation has been imported into the local user?
*In the NetBeansIDE 7.2 graphical editor, you can see the history of the document.*
 - Can you see all the recent changes and the old change?

**It is possible that you are working in a workspace outside the local user rights.**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question, but I ran across this thread while trying to solve a similar (the same?) problem and managed to find a solution, so I'll post it here for future reference.

Are you by any chance running Netbeans on a *nix platform? Chances are you transferred your project files from a filesystem that doesn't support Unix-type permissions - I started having the type of issues you're describing after copying my project over from a NTFS partition, which by default assigned read and write permissions only to my user. `cd` to your project directory and try `chmod -R 777 *` (`rwx` permissions for everyone recursively), then re-open Netbeans to see if your problem is solved. (You might then want re-set a less lenient permission mask on some of the files afterwards, but 777 is a quick way to check.)

(CR)EDIT: @RTOSkit's comment on the OP's question put me on the right track.